# Cannot connect to socket.io with Golang

Tags: go, websocket, socket.io

So, basically here is the code of my socketio server :

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)

func main() {
    server := socketio.NewServer(nil)

    server.OnConnect("/socket.io/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("c")
        log.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        s.Emit("connection", "connected")
        return nil
    })
    server.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, reason string) {
        log.Println("closed", reason, s.Context())
    })
    go server.Serve()
    defer server.Close()

    http.Handle("/socket.io/", server)
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./")))

    log.Println("Serving at localhost:4000...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil))
}
```

and here is how I try to access it within my client (a webpage) :

```js
const socket = io('ws://localhost:4000/socket.io/')
console.log(socket);
```

My problem is that nothing is logged on the client console and the server console when the client should be connecting.

More information :

- I access my  webpage client at http://localhost:4000
- The webpage is loaded correctly
- When I refresh the client, on the server `clode closed client namespace disconnect <nil>`

Answer (score 2):

The version of go-socket.io is only compatible with socket.io protocol version 1.4

```
"Current this library supports 1.4 version of the Socket.IO client.
 It supports room, namespaces and broadcast at now."
```

This server side version isn't compatible with the latest js client libraries as shown in this matrix:

https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/

You should use an old version of the socket.io javascript lib to be compatible with it.

For example version 1.2 as used in their example assets : https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/blob/master/_examples/asset/index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
```